# How can I create a python module that returns another module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I am trying to make python module which when imported behaves exactly like another module.

```
python>
import foo
import fake_foo

help(foo) == help(fake_foo)
```

I need this because I need to add some extra code mafic code inside my `fake_foo` module which dynamically loads the real module from another location.

In case it was not clear the code below does *not* not work for obvious reasons: load_source does return the module, but it cannot tell python to load it to current module.

```
# fake_foo/__init__.py

import imp
imp.load_source('foo', '/path/to/foo')
```

One very important requirement is that I cannot control how people are importing `fake_foo`, I cannot modify the code doing the import, I need to do the whole implementation inside the fake module.

PS. I will need code that would work with py27, py35+ which is high likely 
that would need different logic but once I got it working for one version is shoud not be too hard to find similar ways for other versions.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually trivial. Just replace in `sys.modules`.

In shim module:

```
# mod1.py
import sys
import mod2

sys.modules["mod1"] = mod2
```

In real module:

```
# mod2.py
var = 'hello'
```

Demo:

```
>>> import mod1
>>> mod1
<module 'mod2' from 'mod2.py'>
>>> mod1.var
'potato'
```

That may seem hacky, but it's a *feature* in Python - the import machinery is intentionally allowing such a trick.

> This works because the import machinery is actively enabling this
>   hack, and as its final step pulls the actual module out of
>   `sys.modules`, after loading it. (This is no accident. The hack was
>   proposed long ago and we decided we liked enough to support it in the
>   import machinery.)

From GvR: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-May/014969.html

Comment: Thanks! It seem to be doing exactly what I was looking for, just point few more tests before accepting it. I will also post a link to a practical use: using a shim pure-python selinux module which loads the system selinux module, something that would work in virtualenvs.